# How to convert any number of fixed digits (eg. 10 digits) to RGB or Hex color code?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicolor

I want to create a color code from user's id. I want to assign color to each user.

Actually, I am having an open chat functionality where anyone can chat. And I want to assign a dynamic color to each user. Is there any way to convert users'id to color code or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want every possible user id to be a unique color or just pick a color from a smaller fixed list of possible colors?

Comment: Want every id to be a unique color

Answer (score 0):

I think you should defined your colors list first. 1 -> 30 colors for example. Then just get userId % 30 for the color that will be assign to user

Comment: It is not possible as "30" is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

give user id from 0 to FFFFFF ( 0 to 16777215)
then you can use this macro:

```
#define UIColorFromHEX(rgbValue) ([UIColor colorWithRed:((float) ((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)) / 255.0 \
                                                    green:((float) ((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8)) / 255.0 \
                                                     blue:((float) ((rgbValue & 0x0000FF) >> 0)) / 255.0 \
                                                    alpha:1.0])
```

like this:

```
UIColor *color = UIColorFromHEX(13094098) //or 0xC7CCD2
```

yap sorry the code above is [objective-c] here is the same in swift:

```
convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
        assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
        assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")

        self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    convenience init(netHex:Int) {
        self.init(red:(netHex >> 16) & 0xff, green:(netHex >> 8) & 0xff, blue:netHex & 0xff)
    }
```

Comment: yes my bad thanks for mention it , just updated the answer